# Facebook graph api call to get app access token returns "unknown error"

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I am building a web app integrating with Facebook. I have on Facebook an app id and app secret already.

I'd like to use javascript to retrieve my app's access token to make further app-to-user app requests. I'm following the instructions [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/)

However, I could not make my FB.api call working. I tried

```
FB.api('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token','get',
    {client_id:'XXXXX', client_secret:'XXXXX',grant_type:'client_credentials'},
    function(response) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(response));
    });
```

and

```
FB.api("/oauth/access_token?client_id=XXXXXX" +                                                                   
    "&client_secret=XXXXXXXX&grant_type=client_credentials",                                    
    function(response) {                                                                                                
        alert(JSON.stringify(response));                                                                                
    });
```

but only to get `{"error":{"type":"http","message":"unknown error"}}`

Do I use FB.api incorrectly? At this time, I could not find further documentation showing what I did wrong.

On the other hand, I can manually request it from my browser with the url like:
`https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=XXXXX&client_secret=XXXXXX&grant_type=client_credentials`

So, what is missing in my code? Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to expose your app secret.
Instead you can use the app token directly in your calls (App token does not expire until you reset the secret key).

Facebook Documentation Reference link [access tokens and types](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/access-tokens-and-types/)

Have Fun!!!

Regards,
hbk